# asp.net - Server validation does not fire on first submission

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm having the issue with my Custom Validator using the OnServerValidation. It does not fire when I first submit, but correctly fires afterwards.

In other words, even if I do not fill the data in my text field correctly and submit the first time around, the Validator does not catch the mistake and still accepts the data the field contains, but when I return the form, it then catches the inconsistency second time I submit.

I have 3 validators that validate this field. The other two validators work fine, its only the OnServer validation that is faulty.

My sample ASP Code is for editing is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Date" SortExpression="end_date">
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("End_Date", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;<asp:Image ID="imgEndDt" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/calendar.png" ImageAlign="Middle" />          
    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="hvEndDate" runat="server" Text="?" ToolTip="blah"  BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True"  Height="15" Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEndDate" runat="server"ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" Text="(mm/dd/yyyy), ex:  06/03/2011."  ValidationExpression="([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="ceTestDt5" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndDate" PopupButtonID="imgEndDt"></cc1:CalendarExtender><br />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvEndDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="blah" ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" ValidateEmptyText="True" ClientValidationFunction="currentDt"></asp:CustomValidator>
    <br /><asp:CustomValidator ID="cvExitDateCred" runat="server" ErrorMessage="blah" OnServerValidate="exitDateCheck_server" ControlToValidate="txtEndDate"></asp:CustomValidator>                                                  
</EditItemTemplate>
```

And my Code behind CS code is:

```
 protected void exitDateCheck_server(object obj, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
        Boolean hasCredEndDate = false;
        String personExit = String.Empty;
        if (dvPerson.FindControl("txtEndDate") != null)
        {
            personExit = (dvPerson.FindControl("txtEndDate") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
            if (personExit != String.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("blah", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("blah", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPPersonId.Text;
                    con.Open();
                    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        if (Int32.Parse(rdr["cnt"].ToString()) > 0)
                        {
                            hasCredEndDate = true;
                        }
                    }
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    con.Close();

                    if (hasCredEndDate == true)
                    {
                        args.IsValid = false;
                        SqlDataReader rdr2 = null;
                        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(constr);
                        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("blah, con2);
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add("blah", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPPersonId.Text;
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add("blah", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (dvPerson.FindControl("txtEndDate") as TextBox).Text;
                        con2.Open();
                        rdr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                        if (rdr2.Read())
                        {
                            if (Int32.Parse(rdr2["cnt"].ToString()) > 0)
                            {
                                args.IsValid = true;
                            }
                        }
                        cmd2.Dispose();
                        con2.Close();
                    }

                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = e.ToString();
                }

            }


        }
    }
```

I apologize if I am leaving out any necessary information, I will add if needed.

Comment: You could try adding ValidateEmptyText="true" to your CustomValidator control as it won't fire if your textbox txtEndDate is empty. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Scotty - It doesn't matter that it's empty, the issue is that I'm entering incorrect data that is being accepted the first time I submit, then rejected the next time I submit the same data.